# Does exec("func") convert the inputted function string once or converts it every time the func is called?

Tags: python

More specifically, if I have a code like

```
exec("a = lambda x:x**2")

>>> a(2)
4
>>> a(3)
9
```

Will `exec` be converting the string to a function and evaluating it at the input every time `a` is called or will it define `a` as a callable function once and then just refer to it every time `a` is called after running the `exec()` function

Comment: No, `exec` only runs once. In this case, it is equivalent to just doing `a = lambda x: x**`.

Comment: As an aside, you *almost certainly* shouldn't be using `exec` at all

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga why not? I've hit a problem where I need to dynamically generate callable functions and this is the only way I see it happen

Comment: It is not. It is trivial to dynamically create functions without using `exec`. Functions are just objects, like any other

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how does one do it without ```exec``` though?

Comment: e.g. `def make_function(y): return lambda x: x + y`. `plus_one = make_function(1)`, `plus_ten = make_function(10)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exec` executes the code as if you had typed it yourself into the Python interpreter (or your `.py` file). You can verify this by adding a `print` call inside of your `exec` code:

```
>>> exec("a = lambda x:x**2; print('running')")
running

>>> a(2)
4

>>> a(9)
81
```

Notice how `running` is printed only once.